# Rethinkdb connection causes a oob error

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I am working with rethinkdb and nodejs but when I try to run the basic example, it throughs a oob error.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have the rethinkdb server running by running the rethinkdb command.

Rethinkdb command output:

```
$ rethinkdb
Recursively removing directory /home/tom/rethinkdb_data/tmp
Initializing directory /home/tom/rethinkdb_data
Running rethinkdb 2.3.0~0trusty (GCC 4.8.2)...
Running on Linux 3.16.0-67-generic x86_64
Loading data from directory /home/tom/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
To fully expose RethinkDB on the network, bind to all addresses by running rethinkdb with the `--bind all` command line option.
Server ready, "toms_pc_s4j" 643029e6-a2c3-4abb-b826-64d28310bd36
```

Here is the code:

```
r = require('rethinkdb')
r.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }, function(err, conn) {
  if(err) throw err;
}
```

Which causes the following error:

```
buffer.js:559
  if (start > end) throw new Error('oob');
                         ^
    Error: oob
        at Buffer.slice (buffer.js:559:26)
        at Socket.TcpConnection.rawSocket.once.handshake_callback (/home/tom/Downloads/rethink/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:692:46)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: I can't replicate your error atf1999, can you include your `rethinkdb` npm version number by `npm list [-g] | grep 'rethinkdb'`? Also which version of node are you running? (`node --version`)

Comment: rethinkdb version 2.3.0 and node version 0.8.21

Comment: Hey @atf1999 and @Wittforget, I downloaded a container for 14.04 Trusty and then downloaded RethinkDB from the RethinkDB Install instructions https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/ -- I then used `nvm` to install `node` v5.10.1 and then tried a variety of different `rethinkdb` packages from `npm` and everything seemed to work. Can you tell me how you guys setup your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I got a (somewhat) similar issue running Debian:

```
Creating a pool connected to 127.0.0.1:28015
Setting up listener...
buffer.js:247
  throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
  ^

TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
    at fromObject (buffer.js:247:9)
    at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:115:10)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:94:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/samuel/Code/app/node_modules/rethinkdbdash/lib/connection.js:113:22)
    at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1046:10)
```

After trying different rethinkdb-versions (both the standalone server and the package.json-dependency), trying different versions of both npm and node etc, I installed Ubuntu in pure frustration... But the problem persists.

My code:

```
function connect() {
  return r.connect(config.get('rethinkdb'));
}

export function liveUpdates(io) {
  console.log('Setting up listener...');
  connect()
  .then(conn => {
    r
    .table('tickets')
    .changes().run(conn, (err, cursor) => {
      console.log('Listening for changes...');
      cursor.each((err, change) => {
        console.log('Change detected', change);
        io.emit('ticket-change', change);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

npm -v

3.8.3

node -v

v5.10.1

rethinkdb --version

rethinkdb 2.3.0~0wily (GCC 5.2.1)

Comment: Trying out rethinkdb on ubuntu to see if I can replicate, i'll report back.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was resolved yesterday: https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash/issues/238 Don't know about the original posters problem though?